# How to compare date time saved on millisecondsSinceEpoch in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have saved my DateTime as an int value in a firebase by using `.millisecondsSinceEpoch` for eg `dueDate = 1613286572769`, `entryDate = 1612530000000`. Now I want to query all items with an entryDate in Future, lets say all items with entryDate greater than today's date.

what I am doing is

```
todaysDate = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

carsCollection.orderBy('dueDate').limit(10).where('entryDate', isGreaterThan: todaysDate).get();
```

This is not retrieving me the correct items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All good guys I found out the answer. For reference, I am posting it.
First, you just need to find today's date and convert it.

```
  DateTime now =  DateTime.now();
    DateTime date =  DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
    int convertedDate = date.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
```

Next

```
 carsCollection.orderBy('dueDate').limit(10).where('entryDate', isGreaterThan: convertedDate + 86400000 - 1).get();
```